# How can I make my mob spawners work?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft Bedrock, I built 2 mob spawners. One the drops 20-something blocks underground (I don't remember how many, but I followed a tutorial) and another above ground. The above ground one is bright inside even though there are no holes. I made both of cobblestone. I had the same issue with the first one I built a while back. The underground one is completely dark inside, I went and lit up all nearby caves and still no spawns. I have gone to the other side of the map as well so I know I'm not too close.

Comment: There could be many reasons:
Check out https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359222/is-there-some-added-benefit-to-building-a-mob-farm-above-ground/359242#359242 or https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359216/what-is-the-purpose-of-building-the-mob-farms-afk-platform-so-high/359243#359243

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because mobs only spawn from 148 blocks away from caves, if it is closer, the mobs will spawn in the caves instead of the mob farm. There's a solution to this. You can build the farmer on the ground but only if you lit up all the caves and dark spots in a 148 blocks radius. You can do one out of the two, either build it high up or build it on the ground and lit the caves in a 148 blocks radius, it's up to you. Wish you good luck!